# Why is the runtime of this algorithm (n^2)*(n^2 + 1)/2(i.e. O(n/4))?

Tags: algorithm, performance, runtime

So, a question that my instructor gave us had us find the runtime of this algorithm:

```
{n > 0}
    i := 1;
    while i ≤ n^2
    j := 1;
    while j ≤ i
        j := j + 1;
    endwhile
    i := i + 1;
endwhile
```

In the solution, the runtime here is
n^2(n^2 + 1)/2, which is Θ(n^4).

So, I get that the first while loop has a runtime of n^2, but why does the second loop have a runtime of (n^2 + 1)/2.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second loop is executed `i` times.

So if `i` varies from `1` to `n^2` the runtime is

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n^2
```

Note now that

```
1 + 2 + ... + k = k*(k+1)/2
```

So if you replace `k` by `n^2`, you obtain a runtime in `n^2*(n^2+1)`.
I suppose the proper ident was:

```
{n > 0}
    i := 1;
    while i ≤ n*n
      j := 1;
      while j ≤ i
        j := j + 1;
      endwhile
      i := i + 1;
endwhile
```

Comment: That actually made perfect sense. So, if I am to look at the inner loop, it goes from 1 to n^2 since the loop is executed one time at first, then two times until n^2. The summation gives us n^2(n^2 + 1). Thanks a lot, man. Note: That was how I intended it to be and I edited it now, thanks for pointing it out.